# Auto fill form depending on dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web app that I'm building in PHP, HTML and MySQL that allows users to manage product numbers and claim new product numbers. What I'm hoping to add to this Create Product form below is to have the next product number automatically populate the Part Number (id) depending on the product family selected. Right now I'd just like the first 3 characters populated in the Part Number field which are shown in the first 3 characters of the product family selector. Eventually I'd like it to select the next part number available (example CEG005 if the last highest is CEG004) but obviously I'll need to use the database for that. I know I can do this with PHP if statement but I don't want the page to reload.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

    <tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Product Family</td>
        <td><select class="selectpicker" name='family'>
            <option selected="selected" disabled="true">--Please Select--</option>
            <option value="Express">CEG - Express</option>
            <option value="Carrier">CRG - Carrier</option>
            <option value="Adapter">ADG - Adapter</option>
            <option value="Smart">SMG - Smart</option>
            <option value="Mini">MIG - Mini</option>
            </select>
        </td>

   <tr>
        <td>Part Number (ID)</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='id' class='form-control' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>External Description</td>
        <td><textarea name='ext_description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Internal Description</td>
        <td><textarea name='description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>PRF #</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='PRF' class='form-control' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Publish</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="publish"  value="1" id="checkbox" <?php if(isset($_POST['publish'])) echo "checked='checked'";?>/></td>
    </tr>


        <input type='hidden' name='creator' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?>"/></td>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Product</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Basically if someone selects "CEG - Express" in the Product Family, I'd like the next field (product number) to auto-populate with "CCG"

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page, use Ajax.

Comment: You need to use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and make an asynchronous call to your PHP file. Also, it's a very bad practice to use both double and single quotes for HTML attributes. You should use only the double ones.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Ajax. How would I implement that? Is it difficult?

Comment: It's pretty easy. There are thousands of guides about using Ajax so start by doing some research, try it out and come back if you hit some specific issue..

Comment: @DesignStuff It's not difficult and it's among the basic things for web development.